# Remove item from QListWidget by dropping it outside the widget?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qlistwidget

I have searched the web for possibilities to realize this but haven't found a solution. Is there a simple way of removing an item from the list that is dropped on a non-receiving area or even outside the application's window?

So far I accept the delete key for removing items by means of a shortcut:

```
QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Delete), myList);
shortcut->setContext(Qt::WidgetShortcut);
connect(shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(deleteSelection()));
```

But since I add items to the list via drag and drop, I would like to be able to remove them in the same way, too. The items in the list can also be ordered via drag and drop.

Any hints or links are appreciated.

Comment: Remove them on dragLeaveEvent instead of dropEvent

Comment: @KamilKlimek So you think I would have to subclass the widget to be able to do that? Is there no other way? I would have thought that was a pretty standard thing to want from a QListWidget.

Comment: Try installing event filter and catch dropEvent from it

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

- The drag-and-drop action should be `Qt::MoveAction`
- Ensure the parent of the `QListWidget` (e.g., `QDialog`) has the following:

  - `dragEnterEvent()` implemented
  - `dropEvent()` implemented (ignore the mime data here)
  - `setAcceptDrops(true);`

Ignoring the mime data in `dropEvent()` in a `Qt::MoveAction` should be equivalent to a item remove operation.

Good luck!

Comment: In the Qt Designer, I set all properties to what you suggested and installed an event filter on the list widget, as Kamil said, to catch the dragEnter/dragLeave/dropEvents but the occasions on which an event is fired or not seem almost random to me. The dragLeaveEvent for example doesn't even seem to get fired at all. The event filter approach makes sense to me and the events being fired or not seems a very Qt specific issue, so I posted a more detailed question [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/47939-Can-t-catch-DragLeaveEvent/), in case you're interested. Thanks for your help!